How to enable ChromeOS Support on a Flutter App
I have an internal company flutter app that I have been working on for a few years. We are trying to add the ability to run the app on a chromebook, but found that I couldn't install my app.
I added the following into my analysis_options.yaml to find what I needed to change.
analyzer:
  optional-checks:
    chrome-os-manifest-checks

It told me that I needed to add the following to all of the AndroidManifest files.
<uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
       android:required="false" />

So I added it to my debug, main, and profile AndroidManifest files. And when I ran flutter build appbundle, but the build level AndroidManifest files didn't include it.
How do I get this to work?
